# How to serialize/deserialize a DefaultMutableTreeNode with Jackson?

Tags: java, json, recursion, serialization, jackson

How can we serialize/deserialize Swing's [`DefaultMutableTreeNode`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/tree/DefaultMutableTreeNode.html) to/from JSON with Jackson?

There is a related question
[How to serialize DefaultMutableTreeNode (Java) to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53997112/how-to-serialize-defaultmutabletreenode-java-to-json).
But it asked for Gson, not Jackson (and only
for serialization, not for deserialization).

For `DefaultMutableTreeNode` Jackson's default
serialization/serialization doesn't work, for various reasons:

- It contains children which again are `DefaultMutableTreeNode` objects.
  But it doesn't have the canonical getter and setter methods for that
  (like `getChildren()` and `setChildren(...)`).
- It contains back-references (via methods `getParent()`, `getRoot()`,
  `getPath()`) which would lead to infinite recursion and StackOverflow
  during serialization.
- It has many redundant getter methods (like `isLeaf()`,
  `getNextSibling()`, `getLastChild()`, ...) which don't need
  to be serialized, because they are derived from other properties.

Comment: Try to check also this question: [Why do i get an stackoverflow error when using jackson even though using @JsonIgnoreProperties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55008630/why-do-i-get-an-stackoverflow-error-when-using-jackson-even-though-using-jsonig). There is `MixIn` feature is used to disable cycles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to customize Jackson's `ObjectMapper` with a
[`JsonSerializer`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonSerializer.html) and [`JsonDeserializer`](https://google.github.io/gson/apidocs/com/google/gson/JsonDeserializer.html) specially
crafted for converting a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to JSON
and vice versa.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper()
    .registerModule(new SimpleModule()
        .addSerializer(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class, new DefaultMutableTreeNodeSerializer())
        .addDeserializer(DefaultMutableTreeNode.class, new DefaultMutableTreeNodeDeserializer()))
    .enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
```

The `DefaultMutableTreeNodeSerializer` below is responsible
for converting a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to JSON. 
It writes the `allowsChildren`, `userObject` and `children`
of `DefaultMutableTreeNode` to JSON.
It does not write its `parent`, because that would
lead to infinite recursion and StackOverflowError.
Instead, the parent-child relations are encoded in the nested
structure of the JSON-output.

```
public class DefaultMutableTreeNodeSerializer extends JsonSerializer<DefaultMutableTreeNode> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(DefaultMutableTreeNode node, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
            throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeBooleanField("allowsChildren", node.getAllowsChildren());
        gen.writeObjectField("userObject", node.getUserObject());
        if (node.getChildCount() > 0)
            gen.writeObjectField("children", Collections.list(node.children()));
        // Don't write node.getParent(), it would lead to infinite recursion.
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

For testing you can serialize the root node of a sample `JTree`,
and then deserialize it again.

[image: tree]

```
JTree tree = new JTree(); // a sample tree
Object root = tree.getModel().getRoot(); // a DefaultMutableTreeNode
String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(root);
System.out.println(json);
DefaultMutableTreeNode root2 = objectMapper.readValue(json, DefaultMutableTreeNode.class);
```

It generates the following JSON output:

```
{
  "allowsChildren" : true,
  "userObject" : "JTree",
  "children" : [ {
    "allowsChildren" : true,
    "userObject" : "colors",
    "children" : [ {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "blue"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "violet"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "red"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "yellow"
    } ]
  }, {
    "allowsChildren" : true,
    "userObject" : "sports",
    "children" : [ {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "basketball"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "soccer"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "football"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "hockey"
    } ]
  }, {
    "allowsChildren" : true,
    "userObject" : "food",
    "children" : [ {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "hot dogs"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "pizza"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "ravioli"
    }, {
      "allowsChildren" : true,
      "userObject" : "bananas"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

The `DefaultMutableTreeNodeDeserializer` below is
responsible for converting JSON back to a `DefaultMutableTreeNode`.

The `DefaultMutableTreeNode` is very not POJO-like
and thus doesn't work well together with Jackson.
Therefore I created a well-behaving `POJO` helper class
(with properties `allowsChildren`, `userObject`
and `children`)
and let Jackson deserialize the JSON content into this class.
Then I convert the `POJO` object (and its `POJO`
children) to a `DefaultMutableTreeNode` object
(with `DefaultMutableTreeNode` children).

```
public class DefaultMutableTreeNodeDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<DefaultMutableTreeNode> {

    @Override
    public DefaultMutableTreeNode deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context)
            throws IOException {
        return parser.readValueAs(POJO.class).toDefaultMutableTreeNode();
    }

    private static class POJO {

        private boolean allowsChildren;
        private Object userObject;
        private List<POJO> children;
        // no need for: POJO parent

        public DefaultMutableTreeNode toDefaultMutableTreeNode() {
            DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode();
            node.setAllowsChildren(allowsChildren);
            node.setUserObject(userObject);
            if (children != null) {
                for (POJO child : children) {
                    node.add(child.toDefaultMutableTreeNode());  // recursion
                    // this did also set the parent of the child-node
                }
            }
            return node;
        }

        // Following setters needed by Jackson's deserialization:

        public void setAllowsChildren(boolean allowsChildren) {
            this.allowsChildren = allowsChildren;
        }

        public void setUserObject(Object userObject) {
            this.userObject = userObject;
        }

        public void setChildren(List<POJO> children) {
            this.children = children;
        }
    }
}
```